# using services correctly in playwright

Tags: github-actions, playwright

I am trying to configure a github action to test a frontend that connects to a backend with playwright. I am doing this from the frontend project, so I want to run the backend from a docker image as a service. This is my github workflow configuration:

```
name: Playwright E2E Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, master, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, master, develop ]
jobs:
  test:
    services:
      core:
        image: myimage
        ports:
          - 1865:1865
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 18
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - name: Install Playwright Browsers
      run: npx playwright install --with-deps
    - name: Run Playwright tests
      run: npx playwright test
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: playwright-report
        path: playwright-report/
        retention-days: 30
```

with this configuration unfortunately the frontend does not see the backend that is present on `myimage`, am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your test using `core` as the host to connect with the backend or something else e.g. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? Please include the actual error in your question. Thanks!